# SDP message for screen stream

Tags: java, streaming, rtsp, sdp

When transmitting files over RTSP, at one point, a message is sent SDP such that:

```
...
m=video 3000 RTP/AVP 32
a=rtpmap:32 MPV/90000
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.201/video
a=mimetype: video/MPV
...
```

Information sent in the SDP message, does it have to be different if, instead of transmitting files, transmitting the webcam or screen stream?

If so, how should create the SDP message to transmit the webcam or screen stream?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to describe your media in SDP (Session Description Protocol)! SDP that you provided describes MPEG video stream, sent on port 3000 etc. see details here http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566. To create the message in RTSP, you will have to send it in a response to the DESCRIBE request. See this http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3555.html to find MIME type for your stream. And about creating it... well it is a plain text. Just write it following the rules in first URL.

Comment: Hi Cipi, My question is not how to create an SDP message. My question is what are the values ​​that I have to put to transmit the webcam or screen stream. For example, to transmit video in MPEG format, the value of "m" parameter is: m=video 3000 RTP/AVP 32. One question that I want someone to answer is whether the same parameter "m", should have a different value when transmitting the webcam stream?

Comment: Well you said "how should create the SDP message". Anyway, see the first URL, everything is explained there. Now I don't know the media type of your video stream that you want to transmit, so I can help you more. Can you provide more info about the stream?

Comment: Hello Cipi, First, thank you very much for the help and the second excuse my English, is not good. In the first URL I don't find information about the values ​​that need to transmit the stream of screen :S. I do not know exactly what my type of media to convey, but ... I capture the screen with the StreamPantalla.java (http://bit.ly/i6z548) class, which uses the Java Robot (http://bit.ly/gzCRYx) class. The format of the capture stream (may be) is RGB. I do not know if I can provide more information ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The webcam stream to create the YUV format and for transmission over RTSP / RTP, we must turn to JPEG_RTP.

Furthermore, this means that the SDP message, the parameter "m " (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt page 22) and the parameter "a" (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt page 21) must have the value:

```
...
m=video 3000 RTP/AVP 26
a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.201/video
a=mimetype: video/JPEG
....
```

Greetings!